# Acumatica API - Upload attachment to an Appointment detail record

Tags: api, postman, acumatica

I am trying to attach a file to an appointment detail record. I can successfully attach a file to an appointment using the URL

```
{{baseUrl}}/Appointment/MRO/006301-1/files/image.png
```

However, I am unable to determine the endpoint for appointment detail records. The Acumatica development guide does not provide any insight into related/nested records. As far as I can tell, the appointment detail record is not accessible via a direct endpoint, only with `/Appointment/[uuid]?$expand=Details`

What is the correct API endpoint for upload files to an appointment detail record?

It's my understanding that the Android application uses the API so there should be a matching endpoint.

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible to attach files to detail entities.

Comment: I understood that the mobile app uses the API and it can attach files to detail records, so I was hoping it was possible.

Comment: As Robert Waite mention, details can be saved by making them top level entity. Then they aren't details anymore. Perhaps that's what you're referring to. Also I'm not sure which API Mobile is using, it might not be the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

If an Endpoint does not exists relative to the detail line your could try to define your own via the Web Service Endpoints screen in the Integrations module. You may need to define a screen for just the detail in order to get that endpoint established. Im not at all certain this is going to get you the end result you need but it may be worth a try.